# Install with npm and run command for Jam and Compound.js on OSX 10.8.3 Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, npm, compoundjs, jamjs

When I run installation with npm on OSX 10.8.3 for jam (npm install jam -g) and compound (npm install compound -g), the installation work well and all files go to /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/ as expected.

But the problem is I can't use the commands "jam" or "compound" (command not found).

I tried to change the /private/etc/paths adding the following lines :

```
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/jam
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/compound/bin
```

I restarted my mac and it worked fine for coffee-script but absolutely not for jam and compound

After,
I tried to add Alias of jam index.js as "jam" in the folder /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/bin it doesn't work.

Does any one had this problem and can help me ? I juste moved from 10.6 to 10.8 this week end.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem came with the Brew installation.

Finlay, I removed all node modules an node it self.

First moved to this place : cd /usr/local/Cellar/

After I followed the instructions for Mac OSX 10.8 on the node.js GitHub page https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

> Install Command Line Tools Xcode: Preferences->Downloads install
>   Command Line Tools Note: I installed Xcode 4.5 in /Applications/Xcode
>
> Download node.js src code
>
> git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git cd node git checkout
>   v0.8.2 Compiling Source Code
>
> export
>   CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   export
>   CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   ./configure && make && sudo make install

After I installed npm with the SH installer :

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Now I enjoy compound on OSX 10.8

Comment: Last node builds have npm inside packages.
Can you try to install node with pkg? http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.5/node-v0.10.5.pkg

Comment: I don't know why I did not had the idea to go directly to the website and download the package rather than go on GiuHub and do everything from the command line. But now everything works like that, I would do next time. Thank you!